# Why does Haskell hang upon casting a literal to my type?

Tags: haskell, casting

I have written a wrapper type for Rational that NaN's a division by zero instead of crashing the program. The code compiles without error or warning. Here is (hopefully, all) the relevant code:

```
data SafeRational =
    SRatio Rational |
    SRatioNaN

instance Show (SafeRational) where
    show (SRatio x) = show . fromRational $ x
    show SRatioNaN  = "NaN"

instance Num (SafeRational) where
    (+) (SRatio a) (SRatio b)   = SRatio (a+b)
    (+) _ _                     = SRatioNaN -- Good?
    (*) (SRatio a) (SRatio b)   = SRatio (a*b)
    (*) _ _                     = SRatioNaN
    signum (SRatio a)           = SRatio (signum a)
    signum SRatioNaN                = SRatio 0
    abs (SRatio a)              = SRatio (abs a)
    abs SRatioNaN               = SRatioNaN
    fromInteger a               = SRatio (fromInteger a)

instance Enum (SafeRational) where
    fromEnum (SRatio x)     = fromEnum x
    fromEnum SRatioNaN      = 0
    toEnum x                = SRatio $ toEnum x

instance Fractional (SafeRational) where
    (/) (SRatio a) (SRatio b)
        | b == 0    = SRatioNaN
        | otherwise = SRatio (a / b)
    fromRational a  = SRatio a
```

A problem arises when I attempt to 'cast' a negative literal number to `SafeRational`. Haskell hangs as if it has entered an infinite regress. Positive numbers and zero do not behave oddly, only numbers below zero. Because I use Haskell as a mathematical tool, I do not often play with class declarations and I am afraid that I do not know how to debug the problem. Would someone please explain it?

```
*GHCi> 0-2 :: SafeRational       -- makes Haskell sad
_
```

Comment: Hint 1: look at your definition of `Num`: how do you expect Haskell to calculate subtraction with only the definitions you've provided? Hint 2: If you're using GHC 7.8+, turn on all warnings (`-Wall`).

Comment: Note that in the [documentation for `Num`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num), it says: "Minimal complete definition: `(+), (*), abs, signum, fromInteger, (negate | (-))`.

Comment: So would Haskell produces negative numbers by adding the negative? Is that the regression? WHY IS THERE NO WARNING! Also, I use 7.6.3.

Comment: No, the problem is that because you are expected to provide either a definition for `negate` or `(-)`, so that the other one can be automatically computed via the default definition.  But since you don't have either one defined, Haskell will invoke the default definition of `(-)`, which invokes the default definition of `negate`, which invokes the same default definition of `(-)`, ad infinitum ...

Comment: Didn't they add a pragma to the latest GHC to catch cases like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even without any warnings enabled I get when loading the snippet into ghci (7.8.3):

```
SRational.hs:9:10: Warning:
    No explicit implementation for
      either ‘negate’ or ‘-’
    In the instance declaration for ‘Num SafeRational’
```

i.e. one have to be defined. Their default definitions are mutually recursive:

```
x - y               = x + negate y
negate x            = 0 - x
```

---

Also with enabled `-Wall` you catch another bugs:

```
SRational.hs:26:5: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘/’:
        Patterns not matched:
            SRatioNaN _
            (SRatio _) SRatioNaN
```

What happens when you divide anything by `SRatioNaN`, e.g. `0 / SRatioNaN` ?

---

### Other review comments:

You can define show by:

```
instance Show (SafeRational) where
    show (SRatio x) = show x
    show SRatioNaN  = "NaN"
```

As another `-Wall` warning hints, you (unnecessarily, losing information) convert the `Rational` to `Double` in between.

---

```
(+) _ _                     = SRatioNaN -- Good?
```

Yes, yet

```
SRatio a + SRatio b         = SRatio (a + b)
_ + _                       = SRatioNan
```

reads better (IMHO).

---

Why literal `-2` is transformed into `fromInteger (-2 :: Integer)`? The reason is in the [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html) (3.4 Operator Applications):

> The special form -e denotes prefix negation, the only prefix operator in Haskell , and is syntax for `negate (e)`. The binary `-` operator does not necessarily refer to the definition of `-` in the Prelude; it may be rebound by the module system. However, unary `-` will always refer to the `negate` function defined in the Prelude. There is no link between the local meaning of the `-` operator and unary negation.

So `-2` is transformed into `negate (fromInteger (2 :: Integer))`.

That's odd and discussed feature of Haskell: https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Unary_operator https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/NegativeSyntax

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I used the cast in 'show' to get decimal notation. I have since fixed the warnings from -Wall.

Comment: I have but one other question: Why does Haskell do `negate (SRatio 2)` and not `SRatio (-2)`? If this isn't the case, how does Haskell perform a cast?

Comment: I added a section explaining `negate`.